# How to make a FunctionApp setting slotSpecific using ARM templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

We are using ARM templates to deploy function apps but the slotSetting: true property is not respected and I cannot find any modern documentation as to how to make app settings slot specific.

THis is my app settings snippet in my ARM template

```
{
              "name": "AzureWebJobs.HandleFiscalFrResponse.Disabled",
              "value": "1",
              "slotSetting": true
}
```

the setting and the value works but the slotSettings attribute is ignored silently, no error is shown its just ignored.

What is the correct way to make a function app setting slot specific?

Comment: Do you need arm template for slotSetting?

Comment: Yeah but I figured it out already how to set it MSFT docs are really not the best sometimes for ARM :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have reproduced the issue and able to resolve, please follow the below steps
- Open VS code and create a file using  `.json`  extension and se the below code

Thanks @patelchandni for the ARM Template code.

My  **Filename.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('tar-{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS"
      ]
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "appInsightsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "node",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dotnet",
        "node",
        "python",
        "java"
      ]
    },
    "functionPlanOS": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Windows",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Windows",
        "Linux"
      ]
    },
    "functionAppPlanSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "EP1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "EP1",
        "EP2",
        "EP3"
      ]
    },
    "linuxFxVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Only required for Linux app to represent runtime stack in the format of 'runtime|runtimeVersion'. For example: 'python|3.9'"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'azfunctions')]",
    "isReserved": "[if(equals(parameters('functionPlanOS'), 'Linux'), true(), false())]",
    "slotContentShareName": "[concat(parameters('functionAppName'), '-deployment')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "tier": "ElasticPremium",
        "name": "[parameters('functionAppPlanSku')]",
        "family": "EP"
      },
      "properties": {
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 20,
        "reserved": "[variables('isReserved')]"
      },
      "kind": "elastic"
    },
    {
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('appInsightsLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('applicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      },
      "kind": "web"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "[if(variables('isReserved'), 'functionapp,linux', 'functionapp')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "reserved": "[variables('isReserved')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[if(variables('isReserved'), parameters('linuxFxVersion'), json('null'))]",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[parameters('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~14"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('functionAppName'), '/deployment')]",
      "kind": "[if(variables('isReserved'), 'functionapp,linux', 'functionapp')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "reserved": "[variables('isReserved')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[if(variables('isReserved'), parameters('linuxFxVersion'), json('null'))]",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[variables('slotContentShareName')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[parameters('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~14"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Click on the below marked one to create parameter file  [image]
- Click new as shown in below picture  [image]
- Use the below code in  **FileName.parameters.json**

```
{

  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "value": "zapper01"
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "value": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "EastUS"
    },
    "appInsightsLocation": {
      "value": "EastUS"
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "value": "node"
    },
    "functionPlanOS": {
      "value": "Windows"
    },
    "functionAppPlanSku": {
      "value": "EP1"
    },
    "linuxFxVersion": {
      "value": "3.9"
    }
  }
}
```

- To login to azure portal, run the PowerShell command

```
  az login
```

- Set subscription by using

```
    az account set --subscription "Subscription ID xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx"
```

- Deploy to azure portal

```
    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -TemplateFile "FileName.json" -TemplateParameterFile "Filename.parameters.json"
```

- After execution you will get below one as result in power shall  [image]

9. After deploying into azure portal open the function app and select  **deployment slot**  [image]

**Update**

- I have deployed the below code in Custom deployment In Azure portal
- Thanks, @seligj95 for the ARM Template code.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
        "baseResourceName": {
            "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the resource"
      },
      "maxLength": 15
        },
    "appSettingName": {
            "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the app setting"
      },
      "maxLength": 24
    },
    "environments": {
            "defaultValue": [
              "Dev",
        "QA",
        "UAT",
        "Preview"
      ],
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "Array with the names for the environment slots"
      },
      "maxLength": 19
    },
    "location": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
        }
    },
  "variables": {
        "standardPlanMaxAdditionalSlots": 4,
    "webAppPortalName": "[concat(parameters('baseResourceName'), 'Portal')]",
    "appServicePlanName": "[concat('AppServicePlan-', parameters('baseResourceName'))]",
    "stickyAppSettingName": "[concat(parameters('appSettingName'), '-sticky')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "comments": "This app service plan is used for the web app and slots.",
      "tags": {
            "displayName": "AppServicePlan"
      },
      "properties": { },
      "sku": {
            "name": "[if(lessOrEquals(length(parameters('environments')), variables('standardPlanMaxAdditionalSlots')), 'S1', 'P1')]"
      }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('webAppPortalName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "comments": "This is the web app, also the default 'nameless' slot.",
      "tags": {
            "displayName": "WebApp"
      },
      "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                  {
                    "name": "[parameters('appSettingName')]",
              "value": "value"
                  },
            {
                    "name": "[variables('stickyAppSettingName')]",
              "value": "value"
            }
          ]
        }
        },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
      "name": "[concat(variables('webAppPortalName'), '/', parameters('environments')[copyIndex()])]",
      "kind": "app",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "comments": "This specifies the web app slots.",
      "tags": {
            "displayName": "WebAppSlots"
      },
      "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppPortalName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
            "name": "webPortalSlot",
        "count": "[length(parameters('environments'))]"
      }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('webAppPortalName'), '/slotconfignames')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "comments": "This specifies the sticky (slot setting) application settings.",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppPortalName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "appSettingNames": [
              "[variables('stickyAppSettingName')]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- I have selected the second slot as specific sticky slot in arm template, So the second slot is deployed

[image]

Comment: the problem is not creating the slot the problem is how to make a setting sticky to a non production slot

Comment: Please check the Update in the answer